# PHP why i cannot capture POST variables

Tags: php

i am try do simple php like a login page.
when i put his simple code i can see with echo don't capture login.
I call this php from other php. I have tried with RestClient for testing PHP and i verify don't capture POST variable. Why? i need put same in .htaccess? at this moment i haven't .htaccess

```
<?php

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') { // ¿Nos mandan dato para filtrar?
$login=$_POST['EMAIL'];

echo "\nLOGIN:" . $login;
}else
{
 echo "No POST";
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the field name "EMAIL" or "email"? Case sensitivity matters.

Comment: "Call from other php" - Call how? Are you making a POST request with that call?

Comment: Please show the method (html form / cUrl?) used to send this data

Comment: repeat i am testing to drom RESTclient and force manually POST MODE with header EMAIL and value, this call is right but don't capture value.

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: from other php i am using header('Location:mi.php')

Comment: `header('Location:mi.php')` will make a GET request - please elaborate on what you are doing

Comment: @Roberto: `"this call is right"` - It's nice that you have such confidence in your infallibility, but if everything you're doing is right then what's the problem?  In *most* cases it's safe to assume that the PHP engine isn't broken and that the problem is, in fact, something in your code.

Comment: when i put print_r($_POST), my output is Array
(
)

Comment: It will, if the page with `print_r($_POST)` is loaded by the header redirect you mentioned - this redirect will make a parameterless get request, disregarding any post data sent to the calling file.

Comment: You'll have to use a function build for this like `cURL`. As explained above, the `header()` function will make a GET request. Your `$_POST` array will always be empty...

Comment: If you elaborate on what you are trying to acheive, there will be numerous solutions - either handling post data directly in the posted to file, using include, useing header redirect with get values (as per current answer), saving data in session etc.

Comment: but if i use GET is the same and if i call direct with POST to php is same output. I think must be some of configuration en server but i don't understand why

Comment: @Roberto: Instead of insisting that your code is correct, *show* enough code to *completely* replicate the problem *in the question*.  Nobody can help you if you won't show what's causing the problem and just insist that everything not shown in the question is correct.  Clearly there's an error somewhere.  But we can't see your code, so we can't help you.

Comment: i put all code is only this 10 lines, the call i said i am testing whit RESTClient plugin for firefox put method POST , URL and header with EMAIL=value

Comment: Replace your entire code with `print_r($_SERVER); print_r($_REQUEST);` and see what you get. And the reason David is asking about the rest of your code, is because you mention a header call in the comments, but there is no sign of it in the question code.

Comment: This is may call with RESTClient <img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/1535vl5.png" width="100" height="100">

Comment: when i put print_r($_SERVER); print_r($_REQUEST); this is output
http://pastebin.com/4yZjvpV1

Comment: @Roberto well that screenshot helps explain things - you are making a GET request (so your if(requestmethod==post) conditional is false). Also, if you did set it to make a POST request, the data (email) would go in the request body, NOT as a header

Comment: Offcouse i put get now follow your comments an in code i have chage if to get. But output is same

Comment: Sorry but 2nd part. I dont understand. Me no define html format in php only define <? Php is mandatory that in php file??

Comment: You are misunderstanding how http requests are made. In an http request, post data goes into the request body (see the box that says 'request body' in your REST client). Headers are separate things.

Comment: Keeping your php the same as in the question above, in your REST client, set method to POST and paste the following into the request body box: `EMAIL=mail%40example.com` and all should work as expected - your php is fine.

Answer (score 0):

By means of giving header like this: `header('Location:mi.php')`. It won't pass variables as POST.

You can do it like this:

```
header('Location:mi.php?EMAIL='.$EMAIL);
```

On `mi.php` page:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

EDIT:

Using GET is not good for login, as you are passing user's email on URL.

Comment: or make a `cURL` request. Since this is code for a login page I would vote agains using GET at all costs.

Comment: if i use pint_r($_GET)  and if i call direct with POST to php is same output

Answer (score 0):

Problem was RESTClient this program not is valid for call directly php.

in php original problem was variable EMAIL in FORM is send with "id"=value and not like a "name"=value
But i put my focus with RESTclient and invocate directly WS not give back answer expected.